# How can I retain the alignment of the items in my div when changing the size of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the logos horizontally aligned with the headers in a row. I've ran into issues with resizing the browser and testing the website on different system dimensions. I want to prevent the logos for each header from sitting on top of the text and keep the logos and headers in a spaced row when I change the width/height.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; margin-right: 20px;"><img src="insta_v2.png" alt="instagram" />handle</h1>
  <h1 style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; margin-right: 20px;"><img src="soundcloud.png" alt="soundcloud" />handle</h1>
  <h1 style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;"><img style="margin-right: 8px;" src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" />handle</h1>
</div>
```

I've tried using position: absolute; on the logos and using inline: block; on the container, but neither worked. I can't wrap my head around a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make each `<h1>` into a new flex container, and then wrap the "handle" text in a `<span>` so it is a child element.  Now these two elements inside the `<h1>` will always be in a flex row

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="header-logo">
    <img src="insta_v2.png" alt="instagram" />
    <span>handle</span>
  </h1>
  <h1 class="header-logo">
    <img src="soundcloud.png" alt="soundcloud" />
    <span>handle</span>
  </h1>
  <h1 class="header-logo">
    <img style="margin-right: 8px;" src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
    <span>handle</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```